# $(...).Xxxxxxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is an issue which I constantly experience when using custom scripts with Bootstrap.

In this case I use the LineControl Text Editor:
https://github.com/suyati/line-control.
I included the reference to the script:

```
<script src="editor.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="editor.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

as well as the Jquery, Bootstrap and Font-awesome references.

These links are all included in a Bootstrap modal view with a save button.

In the function `$(function(){`I have:

```
       var editor = $("#txtEditor").Editor();
       $("#txtEditor").Editor("setText", "Hello")

       $(document).on("click", ".btn-save", function (e) {
           var sHTML = $("#txtEditor").Editor("getText");
           console.log(sHTML);
       });
```

It loads the modal view, display the editor and set the text, all fine.
When I click the save button I get the message:

```
$(...).Editor is not a function
```

I have tried many variations and get this constantly. It seems that it does not recognised the plugin's code. I put it in the header as well, but no joy!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would change the $(document).on to $('.btn-save').on('click',function()

Comment: why are you setting the var editor if you are not going to use it? Should it not be `var editor = $("#txtEditor").Editor();
       editor.Editor("setText", "Hello")`?

Comment: `code` var editor = $("#txtEditor").Editor(); editor.Editor("setText", "Hello") I tried that as well, but to no avail.

Comment: Seems another moronic "expert" visit, it was a proper researched and well defined question!!! Rather send me a message and not been a faceless coward removing my statements!!

Comment: Go ahead the next "expert" and downmark it as well, seems. Stupid people!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the reference to the `txtEditor` node in your editor variable, like so:

```
var editor = $("#txtEditor");
editor.Editor();
editor.Editor("setText", "Hello");

$(".btn-save").on("click", function () {
   var sHTML = editor.Editor("getText");
   console.log(sHTML);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Knew there must be a reason why I couldn't get this to work for months, after hours of searching and trying!